# Background color not changing on hover in WordPress custom css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using WordPress so I wrote the custom color to change the background color of the box on hover but it's not working

```css
#project1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 33.33%;
  background-color: red !important;
}

#project1:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="project1"></div>
```

Comment: remove !important for #project1, if you want to override rule inherit from parent class like #parent #project1{}

Comment: @charankumar I have two diffrent text but on hover only the second span text color is change the first span text color is not changing `<span style="font-size: 60px; color: #399bc8;"><strong>01</strong> </span>

<span style="font-size: 40px; color: #3F4143;"> Events</span>`

Comment: That is because applying the styling in the HTML has a higher specificity than `#project1:hover{...}`. Best practice is to put all styling in a separate CSS file, but you can still overwrite it if you use a higher level of specificity, like in [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wauLkbxp/20/). If you want to remove all styling in the HTML and remove any usage of `!important`, take a look at [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/wauLkbxp/21/).

Comment: @SirExotic thank it's working but I have a button it also has a different color but when I hover I don't want to change button color (i want that button color should be same) because button text also span

Comment: I would consider removing the `span` from the button, that seems unnecessary.

Comment: @SirExotic actually it's a built-in WordPress theme builtin button,it' default :(

Comment: @SirExotic i changed the text span to div  now it's working thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `!important` rule is not being overwritten by a new rule that does not have `!important`.

Either remove `!important` from the first declaration, or if you absolutely have to keep it there, add it also to the `:hover` declaration.

```css
#project1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 33.33%;
  background-color: red !important;
}

#project1:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="project1"></div>
```

Comment: I have two diffrent text but on hover only the second span text color is change the first span text color is not changing `<span style="font-size: 60px; color: #399bc8;"><strong>01</strong> </span>

<span style="font-size: 40px; color: #3F4143;"> Events</span>`

Answer (score 1):

Try Removing !important from first rule

```
#project1{

    background-color: red;

}

#project1:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Also, tend to avoid putting !important, rather do the override with better combination of parent selectors.

Comment: I have two diffrent text but on hover only the second span text color is change the first span text color is not changing `<span style="font-size: 60px; color: #399bc8;"><strong>01</strong> </span>

<span style="font-size: 40px; color: #3F4143;"> Events</span>`